Optimizing Product Allocation to Baskets
I am currently facing a challenge in devising an algorithm that optimally solves the following task:
We have a set of products, each associated with specific baskets they can be placed into. For instance, a Kiwi can be allocated to basket 1 or 2, while a Banana can only be placed in basket 1, and so forth. The objective is for the algorithm to divide the products into the smallest possible number of baskets, with the largest group containing as many products as possible.
Consider the following example:
Kiwi - 1, 2
Banana - 1
Apple - 1, 2
Pineapple - 1, 3
Coconut - 2, 3
Plum - 3
The optimized distribution involves segregating the products as follows:
Kiwi, Banana, Apple and Pineapple are assigned to Basket 1,
Coconut and Plum are designated to Basket 3.
In essence, the challenge is to develop an algorithm that efficiently optimizes the allocation of products to baskets, prioritizing the maximization of the product count within the largest basket.

A MiniZinc model can combine the two objectives a find a suitable assignment of products to baskets:
% how many baskets?
int: noOfBaskets = 3;
set of int: Baskets = 1..noOfBaskets;
enum Products =  {Kiwi, Banana, Apple, Pineapple, Coconut, Plum};

%  decision variable: one basket per product
array[Products] of var Baskets: Assignments;

%  which product can be assigned to which baskets?
constraint Assignments[Kiwi] in {1, 2};
constraint Assignments[Banana] in {1};
constraint Assignments[Apple] in {1, 2};
constraint Assignments[Pineapple] in {1, 3};
constraint Assignments[Coconut] in {2, 3};
constraint Assignments[Plum] in {3};

%  an empty basket does not occur in any Assignment
var Baskets: emptyBaskets = 
  sum([sum([Assignments[product] == basket | product in Products]) == 0 | basket in Baskets]);

var 0..card(Products): largestCount = 
  max([sum([Assignments[product] == basket | product in Products]) | basket in Baskets]);

%  objectives are weighted to combine them to a single figure of merit
solve maximize 10*emptyBaskets + 10*largestCount;


Resulting output:
Assignments = [Kiwi: 1, Banana: 1, Apple: 1, Pineapple: 1, Coconut: 3, Plum: 3];
_objective = 50;

